# Unrecognized expression node ArrayIndex using linq with predicate

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Hi i have this query...

```
List<VisitorsVo> lstVisitors = new List<VisitorsVo>();
            var predicate = ReturnPredicateForVisitors(p_htVisitor);
            if (predicate != null)
            {
                lstVisitors = (from n in context.TBL_VISITORs.Where(predicate)
                               select new VisitorsVo
                               {
                                   VisitId = n.VISIT_ID,
                                   VisitorName = n.VISITOR_NAME,
                                   ResidentDuration = n.ENQUIRY_PATIENT_DURATION.Split(';')[0] + " " + n.ENQUIRY_PATIENT_DURATION.Split(';')[1],
                               }).ToList();
            }
```

but i am getting Unrecognized expression node ArrayIndex error how can i overcome...
here i am checking condition in where using predicates....

Comment: Looks like the `Split` may return an array with 1 element. I'd verify that first.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply... Let me verify...

Comment: no it is returning an array with 2 elements...

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this is LINQ to Entities, not plain LINQ. Is your `context` an Entity Framework or LINQ to SQL context?

If so, then LINQ to Entities/SQL will try to translate this expression into SQL, which it cannot do if it contains function calls it doesn't know or that have no SQL equivalent.

My money is on the use of `Split()`; I'll bet that LINQ to Entities barfs on that.

What you can do is modify your query to get rid of the `Split()`, and afterward you can query lstVisitors (which is now just an in-memory data structure, it has no link to Entity Framework) and use `Split()` there.

Comment: @VenkiChikkanti, my guess is also `split`? Will suggest using replace instead (e.g. `n.ENQUIRY_PATIENT_DURATION.Replace(";", " ")`) which has highly like-hood of getting converted into TSQL equivalent.

Comment: Hi vinayC it is working fine... i've used n.ENQUIRY_PATIENT_DURATION.Replace(';', ' ')) instead of n.ENQUIRY_PATIENT_DURATION.Split(';')[0] + " " + n.ENQUIRY_PATIENT_DURATION.Split(';')[1]

Comment: See, LINQ to SQL cannot handle the Split, but it can handle the Replace, which has a T-SQL equivalent (also called REPLACE by the way).

Comment: Yes - I was doing pretty much the same thing and `Split()` was the root of the problem. The DBA had changed the format of data in the field I was using and the char I was splitting on was no longer present.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to split a column that means you can hold that data in two separate columns.

If I were you I'd go to the database design and convert ENQUIRY_PATIENT_DURATION into 2 columns and do it properly. Your code seems very error prone.